# Finding all 3 digit numbers whose digits are all under 6 in Excel Spreadsheet

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a list of numbers from 000 to 999 and i have to pinpoint all the ones which has all its digits under 6, i have tried the following command but it is not quite right, any help will be much appreciated,
=IF(IF((MID(A2,1,1)<6), (MID(A2,2,1)<6), (MID(A2,3,1)<6)),"1","0")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot the AND. Also, you need to multiply result of MID by 1 to trick Excel into converting text back to number.

```
=IF(AND((MID(A2,1,1)*1<6), (MID(A2,2,1)*1<6), (MID(A2,3,1)*1<6)),"1","0")
```

If you want to store your value as a number, this could also work:

```
=IF(QUOTIENT(A2,600)+QUOTIENT(MOD(A2,100),60)+QUOTIENT(MOD(A2,10),6)>0,"0","1")
```

Note, it will return positives even if there's no leading 0s (single and double digit numbers)